# How to use exercise.sty for an exercise with several questions

Tags: exercises

This should be easy, but I just cannot figure it out reading the documentation. Somehow I get confused by all this Exercise/ExePart/subQuestion, etc.

Basically I want to typeset an exercise which consists of an introduction followed by several enumerated questions. So in the end it should look something like:

```
Ex. 1 - Some longish introductory text to a very difficult Exercise 
        blablablabla tralala....

        1. The first question
        2. The second question
               ...
```

Since this is part of an ExerciseList environment I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{ExerciseList}
     \Exercise Some longish introductory text to a very difficult Exercise blablablabla tralala....

     \Question The first question
     \Answer The first answer
     \Question The second question
     \Answer The second answer
\end{ExerciseList}
\end{document}
```

However this does not work. Only the first question appears in the output and all subsequent questions are not visible. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know why but if you use only one `\Answer` at the end, all `\Question`s are shown.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: With the MWE in the qustion, I can not reproduce the described problem. For me, all questions and answers appear in the resulting pdf, although both are numbered with `1.`

Comment: @leandriis add a `noanswer` to the package options to reproduce the described behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is how I understand the package's documentation, so there might be errors in what I write here.

First of: The `\Answer` is only an answer to an `\Exercise`, not a `\Question`.

The enumeration of `\Question`s only works if they follow each other (without an `\Answer` or `\Exercise` in between).

If `\Question`s follows an `\Exercise` with no `\Answer` in between they are considered belonging to the `\Exercise`, if they follow an `\Answer` they belong to that `\Answer`. That's why if you include the option `noanswer` the second `\Question` isn't displayed.

So how would I generate your stuff? Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lastexercise]{exercise}
\begin{document}
\begin{ExerciseList}
     \Exercise Some longish introductory text to a very difficult Exercise blablablabla tralala....
     \Question The first question
     \Question The second question
     \Answer Answer of the exercise
     \Question Answer of the first question
     \Question Answer of the second question
\end{ExerciseList}
\end{document}
```

I guess that's the way you should use the `ExerciseList`. That's the result (without `noanswer`):
[image]